# Story about plant-based aliens who visit earth and are amazed that animal intelligence has evolved here

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plant aliens are unsure what to do about the peculiar biology of earth and discuss the morality of wiping out all of the animal life to allow the plants to evolve. In the end, the aliens attempt to contact a lone human to give us a chance and see what we are about but the human they select is a lumberjack who fells one of the aliens thinking it is a tree, thus dooming humanity.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall where and approximately when you read this?

Comment: Gary Larson did something similar in a one panel "Far Side" strip.

Comment: this would most likely be a golden age of science fiction story.  I initially thought it was by frederic brown, but that didn't help me find it. I think it would be by someone like Robert Bloch, or George Clayton Johnson.